# MongoDB and Java driver: “ignore case” with special char in query

Tags: java, special-characters, case-sensitive, mongodb-java

```
DBObject ref = new BasicDBObject();
ref.put("name", Pattern.compile("TEST_abc" , Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)); 
DBCursor cur = coll.find(ref);
```

Here i want to add special char as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern.compile("TEST_abc" , Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE));
```